# CSS not working properly in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So since the Wordpress plugin Hustle comes with a ton of bugs, I've implemented a fix provided by someone from the Hustle support forums. It changes the position of a clickable link and changes it's content to 'X'. (It's a button to close a pop-up.)

In Chrome, Firefox it works exactly how it should. The X appears on the top right corner of the pop-up, but in Internet Explorer it does not. Also by adding !important it won't work.

If you want to make the pop-up appear you have to scroll down a bit.

URL: www.melvinosenga.nl

CSS:

```
.inc_opt_never_see_again {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.inc_opt_never_see_again::before {
    content: "X";
    font-size: 20px;
    visibility: visible;
}

.inc-opt-close-btn.inc-opt-close-popup {
    display: none !important;
}

.wpoi-nsa {
    position: absolute;top: -35px;right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: which version of IE are you using for testing

Comment: Is the X triggered? Maybe it is behind the other elements.

Comment: Just had a look at your site and if you remove `.inc-opt-close-btn.inc-opt-close-popup { display: none !important; }` the x shows up in ie11

Comment: @Pete It might be a bit confusing, but here's some more explanation: The X shows up, but in fact that's the wrong X. By default there is an X there to close the pop-up, but it doesn't make a cookie to not show the pop-up again.

On the bottom of the pop-up there is some clickable text "Never show again". I hide the class .inc-opt-close-btn.inc-opt-close-popup, this is the regular closing button which doesn't work. So if you remove it the X will show, but this is the regular closing button which I want to remove and replace.

Comment: By clicking the regular closing button the pop-up keeps showing up on other pages and by clicking the never close again link it doesnt. But I just want the pop-up to never show again when you click the X.

Comment: @dutchsociety I've taken a look with inspect element on a different laptop and noticed that the CSS in .inc_opt_never_see_again::before is streaked

Comment: @almartinez Latest build, not sure which version it is but I'm sure it is up to date. Also browserling doesn't work, which has an older version of IE I believe.

Comment: @Melvin I'm just asking because even if your version is up to date but is internet explorer 10 or less it won't work because IE donesn't addmit it

Comment: @almartinez I just checked: IE 11, Version 11.1066.14393.0

Comment: Anyway you need to create a [MCVE] in the question - you cannot just post a link to your site and expect us to debug it for you:  [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Can't see it because my inspect element is crashing over and over again in IE. Sorry :(